# TextView показывает androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText вместо текста

Tags: java, база-данных, строки, textview

TextView показывает androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{5239c42 VFED..CL. ........ 0,469-1440,666 #7f0900a0 app:id/ed_title aid=1073741824} вместо текста в активити HabitActivity. Сначала я принимаю данные из EditText в базу данных в CreateHabitActivity, потом уже в HabitAcivity достаю эти данные и вставляю их в TextView. Вместо данных показывается код, который я написала выше.

CreateHabitAcivity:

```
public class CreateHabit extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHandler db;
    String name, desc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_habit);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        EditText edTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_title);
        EditText edDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed_description);

        TextView saveBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.save_txt);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // DATABASE Inserting Habits

                name = edTitle.getText().toString();
                desc = edDescription.getText().toString();
                db.addHabit(new HabitInfo(name, desc));

                Intent intent = new Intent(CreateHabit.this, HabitActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
}
```

HabitActivity:

```
public class HabitActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    CustomCalendar customCalendar;
    int id = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_habit);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        HabitInfo habitInfo1 = db.getHabit(id);

        String s1 = habitInfo1.getTitle();
        String s2 = habitInfo1.getDescription();

        TextView textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saved_name);
        TextView textViewDescr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saved_description);

        textViewName.setText(s1);
        textViewDescr.setText(s2);
           }
}
```

Сама база данных:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "habitsManager";
    private static final String TABLE_HABITS = "habits";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance
    }  // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_HABITS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_HABITS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE+ " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_HABITS_TABLE);
    }

    void addHabit(HabitInfo habitInfo) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_TITLE, habitInfo.getTitle()); // Contact title
        values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, habitInfo.getDescription()); // Contact desc

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_HABITS, null, values);
        //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    // code to get the single contact
    HabitInfo getHabit(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_HABITS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                        KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        HabitInfo habitInfo = new HabitInfo(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        // return contact
        cursor.close();
        return habitInfo;
    }
    }
```

класс HabitInfo:

```
public class HabitInfo {
    int _id;
    String _title;
    String _description;

    public HabitInfo() {
    }

    public HabitInfo(int id, String title, String _description) {
        this._id = id;
        this._title = title;
        this._description = _description;
    }

    public HabitInfo(String _title, String _description) {
        this._title = _title;
        this._description = _description;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }
    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return this._title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String name) {
        this._title = _title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return this._description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this._description = description;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибок не видно, должно работать. Показанная вами ошибка может возникнуть по такому сценарию:

1. Вы однажды запускали код, когда в переменные `String name, desc;` вы клали не `edTitle.getText().toString()`, но `edTitle.toString()`.
2. Это привело к тому, что с таблице запись с ID 1 имеет указанные вами значения `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{5239c42 VFED..CL. ........ 0,469-1440,666 #7f0900a0 app:id/ed_title aid=1073741824}`
3. После этого вы исправили код на правильный, но запрашиваете всё ещё самую первую запись в таблице.

Коли всё верно, то исправить проблему быстро можно просто очистив данные приложения через системное меню приложений. Иногда достаточно просто удалить приложение (в этот момент база может удалиться, потеряв неверные записи в таблице)